# Woocommerce actionhook not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

we have a problem with a simple woocommerce action hook. The goal is to show specific informations for the german market.

After  two hours of testing with the same actionhook, I reduced the hook to the following:

```
add_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’, ‘additional_text’, 10, 2);

function additional_text() {
    echo '<p>This is additional text.</p>';
}
```

On the opposite, the following snippet works as expected:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10, 2);

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 20, 2);
```

and moves the price from the product summary behind the product summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution to this problem after installing another editor with highlighting. The highlighting looked false. It was due to wrong apostrophes. I used ’ instead of '. Seems like a copy&paste error. And while typing this I recognize that even the stackoverflow code highlighter shows up this error :)